# Quickflip 2 Plugin - only having the image flipped once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Quickflip 2 plugin (http://jonraasch.com/blog/quickflip-2-jquery-plugin/comment-page-3#comment-3562) to have images flip to another image when they are clicked.

However, I am trying to make it possible for the user to do only one click on the image so that they can only flip the image over once and not be able to flip it back.

In my example (http://jsfiddle.net/gJh29/) you can see that you are able to flip the images infinitely many times. I am trying to just have them flip once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for quick flip to work properly, the heights and widths need to be set. Also you don't need to call $(function() {} ); 2x.
You should have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hitmanDX/KHYR9/2/